# C# Get value from variable and write in database table using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am new to ASP.net and C#. I want to insert a value saved in a variable into a database table in SQL Server.

I am using this code:

```
String s; 

SqlDataAdapter inserttext;
inserttext = new SqlDataAdapter("Insert into matching(Text_String) Values(@s)", con2);
```

But it's not working like this.

Comment: What is not working? What error do you get? Please be specific.

Comment: You still have a long reding ahead!
http://lamahashim.blogspot.com.es/2010/04/c-read-insert-update-delete-from-sql.html

Comment: I am not getting any error but when I check the table there is nothing inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more specific with what isn't working. You're not showing the code where you're adding the parameter and it looks like it lacks `using` statements.

```
using(var con2 = GetConnection())
using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, con2))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", s);
    con2.Open();

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're pretty vague, but I don't see where you're adding the parameter to the `SqlDataAdapter`'s command:

```
inserttext.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s",s);
```